# I am getting this error and can not figure out why

Tags: php

> Fatal error: Call to a member function find() on null in C:\xampp\htdocs\Cart\app\Basket\Basket.php on line 2

```
public function update(Product $product, $quantity){
  if(!$this->$product->find($product->id)->hasStock($quantity)){
    //throw exception
    throw new QuantityExceededException;
    }//end if
 if($quantity == 0){
   $this->remove($product);
   return;
 }//end if
 $this->storage->set($product->id, [
   'product_id' => (int) $product->id,
    'quantity' => (int)$quantity]);
}//end function update
```

I am getting this error and can not figure out why. I have pasted the code.  Please note that I am using twig. Any help on this issue would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `$this->$product` is obviously null. You need to figure out why

Comment: I'd guess you want `$this->product` instead of `$this->$product`

Comment: `$product` is the `Product` object you passed in. It probably doesn't evaluate to the name of a property of `$this`.

Comment: Shot in the dark here: `if(!$product->hasStock($quantity)) {...`

Comment: Thanks for the comments. They were very helpful.

Comment: You should avoid having $product and $this->product, too easy to confuse them!